# Не отображаются данные базы данных ms sql в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Я совсем начинающий, столкнулся с проблемой, решение которой найти в поиске не смог.

Создал тестовую БД в Ms sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил эту базу в VS, но никак не хочет показывать те самые "данные" (значения)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи, что я не так сделал?

Спасибо

---

Когда я запускаю проект, данные в таблице появляются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верно ли я понимаю, что в процессе "Конструктора", данные в таблице не показываются?

Понял. Дело в том, что кода-то и нет у меня никакого. Я пытаюсь понять, как вообще это работает, сейчас код такой (никакой):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NTT
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

В видео, которые я успел просмотреть, люди прикрепляют базу - и вот вроде и всё.
Судя по всему, я совсем плохо понял, как это делается.

Comment: ну покажите подключение к БД, подтягивание таблицы (код)

Comment: А, я видимо, на столько нулевый, что и не в курсе, что для подгрузки таблицы нужно код писать.

Ожидал, что уже при подгрузке таблицы, она со всеми значениями самостоятельно переносится в проект

Comment: вот вы обновили вопрос..но кода так и не стало видно....как можно ответить на вопрос, не зная что происходит внутри проги?

Comment: Понял. Дело в том, что кода-то и нет у меня никакого. Я пытаюсь понять, как вообще это работает, сейчас код такой:

Comment: Запомните: нет такой СУБД, как MS SQL. Официально она называется [Sql Server](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server). Кроме того, [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/)  - совершенно другая СУБД. Не путайте их!